Cпециализция шаблона метода класса
Есть много инфы про шаблонные классы, но я так и не нашел про шаблонный метод в нешаблонном классе.
Компилятор очень ругается когда я пытаюсь сделать так:
class c
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void method(const T& arg)
    {

    }

    template<>
    void method<int>(const int& arg)
    {

    }
};

как сделать это правельно?

Зачем специализация? Сделай обычную функцию-член

Ну и когда ругается, надо приводить текст ошибки

В случае GCC есть особенность (баг), что специализация не может делаться внутри класса где был объявлен этот метод/класс.
Можно вынести сециализацию наружу
class c
{
public:
  template<class T>
  void method(const T& arg)
  {
  }
};

template<>
void c::method<int>(const int& arg)
{
}


Всё работает: tio.run
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class c
{
public:
  template<class T>
  void method(const T& arg)
  {
    cout << "common" << endl;
  }

  template<>
  void method<int>(const int& arg)
  {
    cout << "special" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  c x;

  x.method(.5);
  x.method(1);

  return 0;
}

common
special


у меня gcc и в этом была вся проблема https://tio.run/##dY9BagMxDEX3OoVIIWQWDc2im9rMKXIBVxYTgy2bsVwCYc4@9bRZhEAWgi99/pNEpbxPROv6FoRi84w25KozuzQCtBpkQnGJa3HEWNUbAIquViS4QWnfMdAXICqnEp2y/TfPY5/95OAxsV6yP1CWqnjeo5unoXu3XoiUm6K1uKOcUpbdpll8NN1d4BH7xLNBdLxDu3yFrYUpuPjEXfoPPYTJBTkMsGUIr2bbdz3e7z1@DuaxPw1//szaZsEPA8u6/gI
